# some href links are not working in the page

Tags: html

Bit of a weird one - On just one page of a site I've been working, certain html links are not working - the hrefs are relative and are definitely the right links however when you click on them you are not taken away from the current page

http://www.luxury-spa-breaks.com/spas/celtic-manor/spa-days

You'll see that there's only a handful of links that work - all the top nav doesn't, as well as most of the left hand side nav.

This wasn't built using word press, joomla etc. This happens across browsers too.

Your help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in a jQuery plugin, specifically `jquery.tabs.js`:

```
tabs.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        activeTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');

    if(!$this.hasClass('active')){
        $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        tabContents.hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn(2000);
    }

    return false;
});
```

Note at the end of that function that it returns `false`. You're basically having JS prevent the default action on all of your navigation tabs.

Comment: weird as this template is used across the site and this is the only page which problems occur on over a few hundred pages.

Comment: My guess is that this plugin is for loading content into a div on your page, so that users don't have load an entirely new page. But perhaps the div that it's looking for isn't included on the home page, but is on others. (I've been up since the wee hours; it is entirely possible that this comment makes no sense. My apologies.)

Comment: Once again, thank you all for your help. I removed the tabs j query plugin as it wasn't needed on this page and hey presto.

Thanks!! the more you stare at things the less obvious it becomes!